# c++ CopyFile function problem

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hey guys i need to use CopyFile in win 2000 and above platforms.
i want to copy my application to a different folder say c:.

so this works:

```
BOOL didThisFail = FALSE;

    if (CopyFile(L"MyApplication.exe", L"something.exe", didThisFail))
        cout << "File was copied" << endl;
```

but this dosen't:

```
BOOL didThisFail = FALSE;

    if (CopyFile(L"MyApplication.exe", L"C:\\something.exe", didThisFail))
        cout << "File was copied" << endl;
```

Comment: Do you have permissions to write to the root directory?

Comment: well i guess not because i now checked if i can copy to a folder inside C: and it worked. seems stupid that i cant copy to C:. maybe it's because of Win7/Vista limits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetLastError() will tell you why it failed, probably an access denied error.

Comment: How do i use GetLastError in this example? please help

Comment: Refer here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360%28VS.85%29.aspx. There is a link to a example at the end of the article. Call GetLastError() when 'didThisFail' is true.

Comment: if (CopyFile(L"MyApplication.exe", L"C:\\something.exe", didThisFail))
        cout << "File was copied" << endl;
 else
 printf("%d", GetLastError());
 
Then look it up in winerror.h

Comment: didThisFail does not indicate failure in his example. It is a parameter to CopyFile that tells it how to behave if the file already exists.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes copy can fail if you can run out of disk space. When i got stuck in this problem i changed copy command to Move and it worked out for me.

I used to get error code 112.